# Updating selected table records using another table (PHP)

Tags: php, sql

Hope someone can assist...

I have two tables containing fish catches and recording the personal bests of each angler. What I have now done is added more species to the ever growing list.

So I have now backed up the old database (catches_old) and created a new table (catches).

Catches has all the species set to zero.

The only way to pull a unique record is using FishName and Angler together.

What I need is a simple piece of code to check if the weight is more than zero, meaning it has a record, then I would update the record with the old details.

I've tried multiple ways but failing miserably.

Table Old (Specie, FishNm, Position, Fisherman, lb, oz, dr, Drams, PegName, Date)
Table New is the same.

Table Old contains - Old records from catches.
Table new is basically a reset of all records with additional fish names to catch.

Table New contains all fish names and reset to 0 drams.

Table Old now needs to update Table New with the catch records of past catches. Catches that were still not caught in the old table, need not be transferred, just the old catches.

SAMPLE DATA - (not accurate drams calculations lol)

```
Carp - Wobbles - 2 - David Williams - 12 - 4 - 6 - 897 - Willow Island - 21/05/1999  
Carp - Fanta - 1 - David Williams - 14 - 7 - 9 - 900 - Bay of Dreams - 14/05/2004  
Goldfish - Harry - 1 - Fred Ball - 1 - 1- 2 - 258 - Willow Island - 12/05/2010  
Goldfish - Whipper - 2 - - 0 - 0- 0- 0- -
Goldfish - Harriet - 3 - David Williams - 0 - 15 - 2 - 251 - The Fair - 23/09/2012
```

New Code - Using an inner join for two unique fields. Should this work ok as it is failing?

```sql
UPDATE NewTable  
INNER JOIN OldTable  
    ON NewTable.Fishname = OldTable.Fishname AND NewTable.Angler = OldTable.Angler
SET NewTable.Weight = OldTable.Weight
```

Comment: Please post your table structures, some sample data, and one of your previous attempts.. also, which RBDMS is this for?

Comment: Have added some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to take the data from the old, and insert it into the new one, use an insert query with a select statement.  It will insert all matching records.  You don't necessarily have to use php, just use the mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName (Field1, Field2, Field3, Weight)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Weight)
FROM OldTableName
WHERE Weight > 0
```

Note that the order of the fields MUST MATCH.

Comment: Would INSERT work with records that are already in there? Would I need to use update as the records are all set to zero in the new table.

Comment: It won't hurt the existing records.  However, I will point out that if you have a primary key or unique key set that it will fail if it finds a duplicate.  This is where you need to decide, "do i want to add only the records that aren't already in the new table?" or "do I want to overwrite the existing records in the new table while inserting from the old table?"

Comment: Thanks Raythe. I want to update records in the new table with records from the old table. As the new table contains all records for every fish for everyone but at zero. So updating those records with the old ones will keep their place regarding which fish they have caught.

Comment: Not fussed about a primary key, but update is more for me with this one. I am new to SQL and PHP. Would I replace INSERT with UPDATE?

Comment: You can do an update with a subquery, but it's a little more complicated.  So ideal scenario is:

1. Insert records from old table that aren't in the new one
2. Update the weight column on existing records in the New Table with the values from the Old Table

Comment: Thanks Raythe - Problem is that the new table has every angler recorded for every catch, but they are all set to zero. Then I wanted the UPDATE to be used to update records in the new table from the backed up table. EXAMPLE (Species, Name, Weight, Peg, Angler, Date) - Carp - Biggy - 4328 - Willow Island - David - 25/9/12 --- In the new table it will be Carp - Biggy - 0 - - David - . Then I would use the update to change this.

Comment: You will need to do something like this then.

    `Update NewTable
    Inner Join
    OldTable
    on NewTable.PrimaryKey = OldTable.PrimaryKey
    set NewTable.Weight = OldTable.Weight`

Comment: Cool. Although I have no primary key listed, can I use a combi of Fishname and Angler for this part? Secondly when setting weight can I also continue this on with setting all fields from the old table?

Comment: Yes, as long as those values are unique.  I strongly recommend you research the topic **Database Normalization**.

Comment: Thanks Raythe for your assistance

Comment: Keep question - how would you double the unique values instead of a primary key - NewTable.PrimaryKey I would rather have combi of Fishname and Fisherman which would produce a unique field how would I code this?

Comment: It's actually a setting for the database.  If you're using mysql, then I'm guessing you have access to either phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.  Edit the table and set both columns as the PK.  Most people will use a numeric column that auto increments as a PK, but since you've already created your system to have name+fish as your unique value, you will have to use that for your data conversion.  I can say you will later run into problems if you have more than one guy named John Smith catching Walleye.

Comment: Point understood regarding more than one name. Would you think it best then that each my combo of Fishname and and Fisherman should use a auto-increment system? It is one table with a huge list of personal bests so am now thinking that maybe a unique key SHOULD be used - just to make it easier.

Comment: In most instances, you would have a table for your people, then a separate table for their stats.  The table for the fisherman would have a PK like UserID.  I would also have their email address as a Unique Key as well.  Then the stats table would have a PK of StatID and also a column of UserID that references the fisherman table.

Comment: Have constructed some code - see above - but it is not making the changes to the table. Does it look okay to you.